# Decltype and auto in class header definitions, are a few specific cases possible

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

Should it be possible to write the following code? What I'd like to do is that the do_vector_action could automatically deduce the correct return type of the function (the code I actually have has the function defined in a cpp file, not in the header as here).

```
class some_class
{
    public:
        std::vector<int> int_vector;
        auto do_vector_action() -> decltype(int_vector_.size())
        {
            decltype(int_vector.size()) something + 1;
            return something;
        }
}
```

Moreover, I'd like also know, would it be possible to replace typedefs such as

```
class some_class
{
    public:
        typedef std::vector<int> int_vector_type;
        int_vector_type int_vector;
        int_vector_type::size_type size;
}
```

with using decltype or some other construct such as

```
  class some_class
  {
       public:
           std::vector<int> int_vector;
           decltype(int_vector)::size_type size;
  }
```

as the last snippet with decltype doesn't compile with Visual Studio 2012 RC.

Comment: decltype is a C0xx extension (not C++11).  It was first implemented in MSVS2010: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/04/22/decltype-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-3.aspx

Comment: @paulsm4:  `decltype` is a C++11 feature (I'm not sure what C0xx is?)

Comment: While this can be done, it raises the question of whether it *should* be done. I in particular, find the `typedef`s in the first block easier to read than the second block... In particular, if the declaration of the variable and the use are separated, in the `decltype` case you need to (think) map the variable to it's type, and then think on the member types. I don't like *thinking*...

Comment: David, I'm more like just getting my hands and heads around this new syntax and how it feels (my last active usage of C++ was with the C++98 version). You have have point there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
decltype(int_vector.size()) something + 1;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
std::vector<int>::size_type something + 1;
```

which is ill-formed (you are declaring a variable named `something` then... adding one to it?

Your second example, using `decltype(int_vector)::size_type` is valid.  Visual C++ 2010 and 2012 reject it due to a compiler bug<sup>(*)</sup>.  As a workaround, you should be able to declare `size` as:

```
identity<decltype(int_vector)>::type::size_type size;
```

assuming the presence of a standard `identity` template declared as:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };
```

---

(*) The ability to use `decltype` in a nested name specifier was added very near the end of the C++11 standardization process (see [N3031](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2010/n3031.pdf) [PDF]).  This was after Visual C++ 2010 was completed, and support for this addition was not added in Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: VC++ 2012 claims to implement [N3276](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3276.pdf) -- does that include the pertinent changes from N3031? If so, then VC++ 2012 _RTM_ should support `decltype` in nested name specifiers.

Comment: @ildjarn:  I do not know the answer to that question, but I can try to find out (I'm not _that_ familiar with either of these two documents, I just found the one while searching for information on this issue).  Out of curiosity:  where is it stated that Visual C++ 2012 supports N3276?  Visual C++ 2012 does not support the use of `decltype` in a nested name specifier, so while pieces of N3031 may be supported, this particular piece is not.

Comment: It's mentioned in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx).

Comment: @James McNellis: decltype itself was introduced in c++0x and first supported in MSVS 2010, as discussed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/04/22/decltype-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-3.aspx), [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype) and [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/typespecifierdecltype_xml.html).

Comment: James, thanks for the comments. For the identity code too, it greately aids my understanding.

Comment: @paulsm4:  Did I say otherwise?

Comment: @ildjarn:  Thank you; I had searched that page for "N3276" and didn't find it, but I see it now.